# Hydrogen Fluoride, Hydrogen Monofluoride?

Tags: nomenclature

I had a student ask why this is not referred to as hydrogen monofluoride. Similar, we call H<sub>2</sub>S hydrogen sulfide, not dihydrogen monosulfide.

Could we just call those common names, but that by IUPAC naming, it is actually hydrogen monofluoride? Or is it really just hydrogen fluoride. I have seen various answers on other websites, but curious if anyone knows the official answer.

The most common reason I've seen is that because both H and F has a single site open for bonding that there is no other combination possible (so no need for numerical prefixes).

Comment: Related: [Why is CaCl2 called calcium chloride?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/14141/7951)

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/59396/34388

Comment: VTC as duplicate. I don't think it makes sense to not close this. Not closing this would imply that we would allow one question for every single inorganic salt e.g. LiF, LiCl, LiBr, LiI, NaF, NaCl.......... MgF2, MgCl2, ...........

Comment: Thank you all, the answer in the first post was more than sufficient. I agree, it is a duplicate

Comment: One helpful thing to keep in mind (and you're clearly already keyed into this) is that IUPAC nomenclature is intended to reduce *ambiguity* and create *consistency* with rules that are as *simple* as possible.